# NOT IN vs MINUS not yielding same result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

[fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f6c01/3)

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME 
FROM employee MINUS 
SELECT NAME FROM salary;

SELECT DISTINCT NAME 
FROM employee 
WHERE NAME NOT IN (SELECT NAME 
                   FROM salary);
```

Was thinking the result should be the same but it isn't. Anyone explain why it's not?

Comment: Please tag your question with the appropriate server brand. In SQL Server, `MINUS` isn't a keyword, and your first query is actually two queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MINUS` is not a supported keyword in MS SQL Server.  If you look at the execution plan it is parsing  `MINUS` as a table alias for `employee` - it's the equivalent of:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [MINUS.]NAME 
FROM employee [AS] MINUS
```

The entire query is then parsed as two separate queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [MINUS.]NAME 
FROM employee [AS] MINUS 
<-- break -->
SELECT NAME FROM salary
```

where the implied terms are in brackets (`[]`)

SQL Fiddle does not seem to be showing the multiple result sets properly.

The equivalent keyword to Oralcle's `MINUS` in SQL Server is `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME 
FROM employee EXCEPT 
SELECT NAME FROM salary;
```

Comment: It's just two queries -- `SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM employee AS [MINUS]` and `SELECT NAME FROM salary;`. Hooray for optional semicolons!

Comment: @JeroenMostert I agree - but SQL Fiddle isn't showing the results of the "second" query like SSMS would.  If you add a semicolon between them it works.

Comment: Call me a snob, but that's why I prefer my local servers to SQL Fiddle. :-)

Comment: How do you know that sql server is the rdbms?  It could be oracle, which does support the keyword minus.

Comment: @JeroenMostert The semicolon handling is not related to the server, but to the SQL client. And you should really get used to using them: https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I'm not sure why you're addressing that remark to me personally -- "hooray for optional semicolons" was not meant in earnest.

Comment: @DanBracuk The question is tagged `sql-server-2008`.